# knife configure --initial using an existing client

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I want to initialize a system as a **Chef workstation**. I was going through the *command* "`knife configure --initial`" for the same.

From the documentation, I understood that this asks for the name of a new clientname and contacts the API service to register a new client with the service.

My question is, what would be the steps for using an existing client name configured using the **Chef server**?

Is there an alternative to :
`knife configure --initial
Please enter a clientname for the new client: ____`

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post.

The SO community values when you show your own efforts, so you might want to add some code. 



Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using an existing client, you just have to write your own config file. If you are using the latest version of Chef, you can use a `.chef/credentials` file like

```
[default]
client_name = yourusername
client_key = /path/to/user.pem
chef_server_url = https://mychefserver.com/organizations/myorg
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was reading up on the role of knife.rb file and I read that the only necessary components for the chef workstation to function are node_name, client_key and chef_server_url and during the bootstrap of chef node, validation_client_name and validation_key are copied over to the new node. 

Could you help me understand where the the value entered for "please enter a clientname for the new client" during the interactive configuration of knife.rb in the workstation is used?

Comment: In `knife.rb`, that becomes the `node_name`. This is fairly confusing which is why we allow `client_name` instead as an alias in the newer `credentials` file.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.
Thanks a lot!